# how to load a pdf file directly from the folder without opening the dialogue box? in c#

Tags: c#

hi I want to open a pdf file directly from the folder without adding any button in c#.it means I want to load pdf file in c#. hi I want to open a pdf file directly from the folder without adding any button in c#.it means I want to load pdf file in c#.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean with "loading". If you want to read the context of the file, you can use this;

```cs
File.ReadAllBytes("document.pdf");
```

If you want to open the PDF in your default browser, you can use this;

```cs
Process.Start("document.pdf");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i just want to open a pdf file from a particular folder without opening a dialogue box

Comment: If you want to open a PDF file in your default browser, try the second method.